# Elasticsearch snapshot

Tags: elasticsearch

If an elasticsearch snapshot contains multiple indexes ( ex: wikipedia, ehow, howStaffWorks ), can we load only one of these indexes into elasticsearch server or all the indexes have to be loaded when loading the snapshot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html) on the elasticsearch site shows restoring specific indexes from a snapshot:

```
curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/_snapshot/my_backup/snapshot_1/_restore" -d '{
 "indices": "index_1,index_2",
 "ignore_unavailable": "true",
 "include_global_state": false,
 "rename_pattern": "index_(.+)",
 "rename_replacement": "restored_index_$1"
}'
```

See the `indices` above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. No need to load all the indexes.

```
curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/_snapshot/my_backup/snapshot_1/_restore" -d '{
  "indices": "index_1",
  "ignore_unavailable": "true",
  "include_global_state": false,
  "rename_pattern": "index_(.+)",
  "rename_replacement": "restored_index_$1"
}'
```

For loading all indexes you can use Following code,(sense plugin)

```
PUT  /_snapshot/my_backup/snapshot_1?wait_for_completion=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can load.

```
$ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/' -d '
        "index" : {
            "number_of_shards" : 3, 
            "number_of_replicas" : 2
```